# Stored Procedure for finding N Level Child List

Tags: javascript, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Recently i came across one problem of finding N Level Child from tables.

Let say we have following list of tables:

```
Table: **Country**
PKCountryID
CountryCode
CountryName

Table: **State**
PKStateID
FKCountryID
StateCode
StateName

Table: **Area**
PKAreaID    
FKStateID
AreaCode
AreaName

Table: **Customer**
PKCustomerID    
FKAreaID 
CustomerCode
CustomerName and so on....
```

Here we need to find a way by which we can get N level Treeview with All Columns

Just Like

```
   >Country
            Country Table Column         
            Foreign Key Column of Country Table(Here : FKStateID)
            >State
                    State Table Column         
                    Foreign Key Column of State Table
```

and so on till N Level.

Is there any solution?

Comment: The easy solution for this would be to load the child nodes on demand. First, load up all of your Countries(if countries is top level in the hierarchy) then add all countries to the root node. On expand of a country make a database call to load up all the States of the selected country and append them to the Country node currently selected in the tree view and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can basically create the hierarchy using a CTE.  If you build hte CTE properly, it will load as many levels as you need.  However, I've built these before and you must be very careful in writing the code and how you write it or else performance may suffer.

Do try to use CTE to grab the information and determine if that will fit your need.